# My oat bread is drier than the Sahara

Tags: bread, oats

I made some high protein / low calorie oat bread using a recipe I found online.

The recipe is:

- 12 egg whites
- 120 g oat flour (from rolled oats)
- 28 g psyllium husks
- 70 g whey protein
- 2 tsp baking powder
- 1/2 tsp salt
- Mix all ingredients then bake for about 40 minutes at gas mark 3.

Everything about the bread is fine except that it's extremely dry and difficult to swallow. The bread feels and looks ok until I try to eat it.

Is there anything I can add to the recipe to improve it when I make it next time?

Comment: Honestly, it's so far from the flour+water+salt+yeast formula that I don't know where to begin. Pretty much everything in the recipe you gave is dry, and egg whites have a drying effect in baked goods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your oat bread is a quick bread recipe. Keep in mind that advice for quick breads is going to be very different than advice for yeast risen / glutinous breads.

In quick breads, the structure of the loaf is provided by egg protein and the moisture is mostly provided by fat.

Your recipe uses only egg whites which, as J K commented, have a drying effect on baked goods. The yolks in whole eggs have fat that help keep things moist.

Besides the water in your whites there is no other liquid and no fat in this recipe. I'm surprised that you were able to swallow it at all. This is a problem that plagues low calorie baked goods. You can make it a bit better than this recipe but don't expect it to ever be as good as recipes that have fat in them.

This recipe is so dry that I would have a hard time making suggestions on how to improve it without turning it into a new recipe that would have to be tested.

Some things to look for in recipes that will make them better:

1. Some added fat
   It doesn't have to be a lot. Some quick breads have a lot of fat. Even a little bit will help. Some recipes will use part fat and part applesauce. The pectin in the applesauce helps make things tender and the extra liquid helps keep things moist.
   As I said above, whole eggs are also nice for some good fats.
2. Less of the unswallowable ingredients
   Those psyllium husks are going to be bone dry no matter what you do. If there is a lot of that in there have a glass of milk handy when you try and swallow it.
3. Added liquid
   Not all recipes use added liquid but some like buttermilk can be very tasty additions.

My personal opinion is that I would rather eat less of something that tastes good than a lot of something gross. Low-calorie can be taken too far.

Another alternative is to abandon the bread idea altogether. This recipe would be very similar to low-calorie granola recipes if rolled out thinly.

Comment: I agree with most of what you are saying here, but think that it doesn't go far enough. There is not just fat missing; it misses starch, and possibly sugar. Standard breads (be it quick breads or yeast breads) store most moisture in the hydrated starch than in the fat. The OP would need about 3-4 kg of starch to start getting close to a normal bread with the 12 eggwhites.

Comment: I agree, the number of egg whites is excessive. I have to admit I haven't tried a quick bread with only oat flour but it does provide the starch. This is kind of why I didn't want to try and fix this recipe but instead describe what a good recipe looks like.

Comment: I haven't made oat flour bread either, but 2-3 egg whites per 1 kg of flour already have a noticeable drying effect (even though the result stays palatable), so for 120 g oat flour, even one egg white is likely to make it quite dry, and the added protein and psyllum just make it worse. Of course, the psyllum here seems to be just a gluten substitute, so getting rid of it completely is not the solution either - but it cannot do its job of adding flexibility to gluten free flour if there is practically no flour to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not averse to adding fat, it's just that there was none in the recipe. I'll increase the ratio of starch to protein and add some fat. Do you recommend I add oil or hard fat?

Comment: You might also experiment with whole eggs rather than whites, for the same total. Or start from a different recipe.

Comment: Oil and hard fat will both work, yield slightly different texture. If you decide on nutritional basis: the calories are the same per gram, saturated vs unsaturated fatty acid content can differ, and discussing the meaning of these plain facts would be off topic nutritional advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Butter needed in it. Ingrediences lack butter eggs just hold the flour together giving breads and cakes strength. I know this because my father was army chef ...  and use to tell me secret cooking tips.